# Items in view go out of screen

Tags: react-native

*I put images to View with `.map`. But when I have add 5 items last image goes out of screen. because I give  width:'25%' to view.*

*I want my images which are out of screen go next row. How could I do this ?*

**This is my method :**

```
renderImages() {
 return images.map((items, key) => 
  {
      return (
            <View key={key} style={{ backgroundColor: items.renk, width: '22%', marginLeft: '3%', marginTop: '2%',alignItems: 'center' }}>
               <Image source={items.img} style={{ height: 60, width: 60 }} />
            </View>
      );
   }
    );
}
```

**this is my render :**

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View> 

       <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          {this.renderImages()}
        </View>
       </ScrollView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't do it with view tag. You can use `flatlist` and give `column prop` to value 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code View component like this:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap:'wrap' }}>
          {this.renderImages()}
        </View>
```

also it is unecessary to set the style of scrollview to flex:1 if its not set into horizontal: true.